# How can I access firstViewController's webView after dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

My env,

```
iOS6
Xcode 4.5.1
application for iOS5 or later
```

I use two ViewControllers.

FirstViewController has webView and which segue modal to call SecondViewController.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"foo" sender:self];
```

Then, after close SecondeViewController I want to reload webView in the FirstViewController.
How can I reload this?

I use the following code for close the SecondViewController.

```
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{  }];
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to call:

```
[webView reload];
```

at a suitable place like, viewWillAppear, or  viewDidAppear delegate methods of firstViewController.

You may also reload the webView through the completion block of :

```
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ [self.firstViewController.webView reload]; }];
```

But for this you must have instance of firstViewController available in the completion block(scope). For this you may declare your firstViewController in appdelegate or any other way. Also you need to set webView as a property to the firstViewController.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can do well with using reload in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` has a method called `reload` which you might try out.

You could call it from your `dismissViewControllerAnimated` completion block, or you could call it from your first controller `viewWillAppear` (but in this case, you should make sure that this will not cause excessive reloading).

Answer (score 0):

Removes the receiver from its parent in the view controller hierarchy.

```
- (void)removeFromParentViewController
```

You can follow  [Apple Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier%3asender%3a)
Hope this will help you out.